# Data Breakpoint failure in IAR embedded workbench for structure members

Tags: debugging, microcontroller, breakpoints, iar

I am trying to put data breakpoint in my IAR embedded work bench for one structure member. Just I want to see in complete project, who is changing that structure member. Example syntax for that structure member is as follows:
Structure_Variable.Sub_Structure_Member1.Sub_Structure_Member2.Sub_Structure_Member3

But whenever I am trying to put these breakpoint, it will give me following error "Failed to set Illegal breakpoint".
Data breakpoints are working for Variables, it is having issue only with structure members.
In the same way "Log data breakpoint" for structure members is also not working, and it is giving same error.

Comment: Which version of the IAR workbench (architecture, version number) are you using?

Comment: Version Number: 8.40.2.22891